# How to modify the code to not get appendchild error

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have been trying to use the below code but whenever I am trying to run it in react file I am getting this error
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild')" error .
At first I found a design from codepen, then  I tried to integrate it in react code but error is enevitable
Thus I am in need of finding answer to it

```
const container = document.getElementById('container');
const circlesArr = [];

for(let i=0; i<15; i++) {
    circlesArr[i] = [];
    for(let j=0; j<15; j++) {
        const circle = document.createElement('div');
        circle.classList.add('circle');
        container.appendChild(circle);
        circlesArr[i].push(circle); 
    }
}
function growCircles(i, j) {
    if(circlesArr[i] && circlesArr[i][j]) {
        if(!circlesArr[i][j].classList.contains('grow')) {
            circlesArr[i][j].classList.add('grow');
            setTimeout(() => {
                growCircles(i-1, j)
                growCircles(i+1, j)             
            }, 100)         
            setTimeout(() => {
                circlesArr[i][j].classList.remove('grow');
            }, 300);
        }
    }
}
circlesArr.forEach((15, i) => {
    cols.forEach((circle, j) => {
        circle.addEventListener('click', () => {
            growCircles(i, j);
        });
    });
});
  return (<div id="container" className="container"></div>)}
```

The CSS code

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 450px;
}
.circle {
    background-color: #5295F1;  
    height: 14px;
    width: 14px;
    transition: transform 0.3s linear;
}
.circle.grow {
    transform: scale(2);
}
```

Comment: you're probably running the javascript before the element is loaded - that's the most common problem that results in this most common error

Comment: Yeah but I want this code in React

Comment: fair enough - what stops you from writing a single line of it?

Comment: I am facing issues when I am running this on React

Comment: is the issue the `appendChild` error? again ... is your javascript code running too soon?

Comment: Yeah I am facing appendChild error when I am running on Reacct

Comment: OK, so is the javascript code running before the DOM has laoded?

Comment: How are you incorporating this code into the rest of your code?

Comment: chech the modified

Comment: I don’t understand your code. You seem to be creating the container div via react but the constant container seems to be set before that ( so it will be null).

Comment: So how to fix this ?

Comment: @User As other's have mentioned, whenever your script here is run (wherever it is run; you still haven't really clarified that), document.getElementById('container') ends up returning null. So calling null.appendChild() throws the error you're seeing.  You need to clarify to us what a "react file" is and then you must show us how you are creating this DOM element with an ID="container" with React.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the code before `return` is inside your component's body. It means you are trying to get an element with id "container" before rendering it so at that point the `document.getElementById('container')` returns null which doesn't have `appendChild` method.